# SSH client that can play sound based on Regex found in output

Tags: windows, gratis, regex, ssh

Today I am using Putty with ANSI colors to highlight problems. In error cases I have injected `\a` (bell sound) and configured Putty to play a sound in that case. Unfortunately this solution is limited to a single sound, which is not yet sufficient.

I am looking for an SSH client

- for Windows (7 SP1 x64 at least)
- that authenticates via key file (PPK)
- that allows to define Regex and play different sounds for each Regex
- is gratis / open source